# Function returning a result from the wrong thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, backgroundworker

I have a program that completes tasks given a context of what the user wants it to do, and allows the user to run a task asynchronously while they execute tasks on the main thread. However, if a user fires off an asynchronous task (using the `BackgroundWorker`), and then tries to complete a task on the main thread before the BackgroundWorker task finishes, the result from the main thread **is returned to the `BackgroundWorker`**.

This is a simplified version of how I'm calling the tasks:

```cs
public object DoTask(TaskType c)
{
    if (c == TaskType.ReadLine) 
    {
        return Console.ReadLine();
    }
    else if (c == TaskType.LongTask)
    {
        //imagine this takes a long time.
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Here's the `BackgroundWorker` method:

```cs
public void getLongTaskDone(DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var result = DoTask(TaskType.LongTask); //this is the issue
}
```

And here's how I'm calling it:

```cs
//Task takes a long time.
var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.DoWork += getLongTaskDone;
bw.RunWorkerAsync();

//Task takes barely any time.
var result = DoTask(TaskType.ReadLine);
```

Whatever I enter into the `ReadLine` task then gets returned to the BackgroundWorker "result" variable, instead of the result of the task that takes a long time. What would be causing this issue? How would I redesign this to fix it?

Comment: `The Console.ReadLine returns to the BackgroundWorker thread` - how did you come to conclusion that this is what happens?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean witb *"return to"*?

Comment: `var result = DoTask(TaskType.ReadLine);`: get a return value in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event. What problem is this method supposed to solve?

Comment: I came to that conclusion because whatever I enter into the `Console.ReadLine` then gets returned to the `BackgroundWorker` "result" variable, instead of the result of the task that takes a long time.

Comment: @LarryTang Your task inside `BackgroundWorker` does not try to read the console in the first place, so there is nowhere to "return" the value. It is only possible in the case your `TaskType.ReadLine` and `TaskType.LongTask` values are equal to each other.

Comment: They aren't, they're members of a defaultly assigned enum.

Comment: First you are raising an event, why are you expecting result from the event?
Second try using something else instead of Console.ReadLine as it will wait for user input.

Comment: Please double check that, at runtime too. If they are indeed different, then we are back to the question of how you came to that conclusion. You have two different variables named `result`, did you possibly confuse them?

Comment: I am not expecting a result from my event, my point was that the function I am calling inside the `BackgroundWorker` event returns the value of a call from the main thread, instead of what it should.

Comment: I wrote this as an minimal example, but the full code of the problem can be seen [here](https://github.com/c272/algo-lang/blob/master/Algo/Evaluation/Visitors/Code%20Flow/AlgoAsync.cs) and [here](https://github.com/c272/algo-lang/blob/master/Algo/Evaluation/Visitors/Code%20Flow/AlgoFunctionManager.cs), lines 59 and 51 onward respectively. I'm double checking their runtime value now. Line 82 of the first file is where the error occurs.

Comment: You started a background thread with 'LongTask' which sleeps for a while then returns 5 to getLongTaskDone and does nothing with the result. In the meanwhile in main thread you are doing Console.ReadLine which is waiting for user input.

Comment: `I wrote this as an minimal example` - but it's not reproducible. Can you come up with complete code, including the enum definition, and indicate what and where is wrong?

Comment: I will, apologies.

Comment: The `BackgroundWorker` is such an awkward and outdated tool to use. Why not use a modern tool like the [`Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task) class, that has also language support with the [`await`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await) operator?

Comment: hey @LarryTang, would it help if we convert from `Background Worker` to `Task` with `Async-Await` approach